# Django - ImportError at /blog. No module named urls

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and in the process of learning. While doing some tutorial exercises I ran into some errors which I need help with.

Error: ImportError at /blog. No module named urls

The urls.py file under the app named 'blog' is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.blog.views import archive

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',archive),
                       )
```

The views.py file under the app named 'blog' is

```
# Create your views here.
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mysite.blog.models import Blogpost

def archive(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html")
    c = context({'posts': posts })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

The urls.py file under the project 'mysite' is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Traceback:

```
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_request
  67.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  531.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  420.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /blog
Exception Value: No module named urls
```

**Structure of Project/App:**

1. mysite

   - manage.py
   - *init*.py
   - settings.py
   - urls.py
   - wsgi.py
   - blog

     - *init*.py
     - models.py
     - views.py
     - urls.py
     - tests.py
     - Templates - archive.html

**Python path**

> ['D:\Super Developer\Proj\mysite',
>   'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip', 'D:\Super
>   Developer\Python\DLLs', 'D:\Super Developer\Python\lib',
>   'D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\plat-win', 'D:\Super
>   Developer\Python\lib\lib-tk', 'D:\Super Developer\Python',
>   'D:\Super Developer\Python\lib\site-packages']

Comment: Will you be providing the traceback as well?

Comment: Traceback has been added

Comment: @stalk what do I do to fix it?

Comment: Please show us the contents of mysite.blog.urls

Comment: @Izzad-DinRuhulessin the contents are included above

Comment: In your project settings, is `URL_CONF` set correctly?

Comment: ...and could you also provide the structure of your project/app?

Comment: was initially ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'. later changed it to 'urls'. Still continue to face the same error.

Comment: @Stefano I have just added the project/app structure

Comment: ...and sorry, forgot: one more, can you print your python path? eg. go into django shell: `./manage.py shell`, then `import sys` and `sys.path`. The main folder containing manage must be in it.

Comment: @Stefano I have updated the python path. The main folder containing manage is included in the path.

Comment: I'd say that you have import error in blog.urls, try commenting out "    url(r'^$',archive)," to see if that's the issue

Comment: @JureC. I did as you suggested but that makes no difference. When I commented out "url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls'))," the admin interface loaded

Comment: Last questions: is 'blog' in your installed_apps (I think so). But more important: what are your imports in "blog.views"? Sometimes unnoticed circular imports make the failure difficult to spot

Comment: @Stefano, I have included views.py under the app blog above for your reference

Answer (score 5):

```
url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.blog.urls')),
```

This may need to be changed to

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

Note: no 'mysite' prefix.

Comment: Hi Rohan, Tried removing the 'mysite' prefix. I continue to see the same Importerror

Comment: You just solved my problem by accident. I had to **add** _mysite_. Thanks, +1.

Comment: just remove project name.

Comment: remove `mysite`, `FirstBlog` or whatever b4 the `blog` of that string

Answer (score 1):

In blog's urls.py, you import

`from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url`

But in project's urls.py, you use

`from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url`

Is this indented? The latter seems to fail at least in my env.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you did the declaraion for media or static urls in your app url file using

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve'
, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
  ),
```

instead of in the application url file.

I had the same problem, changed this and I didn't have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a **__*init*__.py** file in your blog folder.

Comment: __init__.py is very much in place in the blog folder

Answer (score 0):

I think `patterns` cannot have comma after last element:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',archive), <-- delete this comma
)
```

also try to run `manage.py shell` and `import blog.urls`, if there's not raised any exception in there

Comment: Hey, I tried what you suggested but I get "ImportError. No module named blog.views in the shell. what does that mean?

Comment: what about `import mysite.blog.urls` ?

Comment: I get ImportError: No module named blog.urls

Comment: is `blog` (or `mysite.blog`) in yours `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: 'blog' is included under INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('mysite.urls')),
```

Comment: It is preferable to explain what the code does, and how it answers the question

Comment: please impove your answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine was going through some django tutorial and got the same error. The mistake he made was in the file structures. In the new version of django, it creates two directory levels for example mysite/mysite and he tried putting the blog folder in mysite/blog instead of mysite/mysite/blog. After making that change, it all seemed to work well. Try to look at your structure and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Django 1.6 or newer. Due to some changes in the framework, this code wouldn't work. Use 1.5 or this code in blog's urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from blog import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.archive),
    )
```

And this in views.py:

```
    from django.template import loader, Context
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from blog import models 

    def archive(request):
        posts = models.BlogPost.objects.all()
        t = loader.get_template('archive.html')
        c = Context({ 'posts': posts })
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```